# Find all positive real solutions to the system:

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

Find all positive real solutions to the system:
$$x_1+x_2+...+x_n=9$$
$$\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2}+...+\frac{1}{x_n}=1$$
I have tried using the fact that $x_1+x_2+...+x_n-8=\frac{1}{x_1}+...+\frac{1}{x_n}$, or that the trivial solution to the second equation is $x_1=x_2=...x_n=n$, and then decomposing those fractions into sums of smaller fractions, but I have not come to any meaningful conclusions.

Comment: The arithmetic mean harmonic mean inequality may be of interest.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. So AM-HM inequality would mean : $9/n \geqslant n$ which would mean one would only have to examine the cases n=1, n=2, n=3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by using Cauchy inequality we have $(x_1+...+x_n)(1/x_1+...+1/x_n)\ge n^2$and $(x_1+...+x_n)(1/x_1+...+1/x_n)=n^2\to \frac{x_1}{1/x_1}=...=\frac{x_n}{1/x_n}\to x_1=...=x_n$so $n=3,2$and in the case $n=3$ solution is $x_1=x_2=x_3=1/3$.you can easily solve the problem in the case n=2

Comment: Yes, thank you, its easy to solve once you know the inequality.